# pg_rman restore

Tags: postgresql

I'm learning on postgreSQL(9.0.1) especially [pg_rman](http://code.google.com/p/pg-rman/)(1.1.2) these days...

What I've done is .....

1. create two tables t1, t2;
2. pg_rman installation.
3. pg_rman init -B $RBACKUP_PATH
4. pg_rman validate -B $RBACKUP_PATH
5. drop tables t1, t2;
6. pg_ctl stop -m fast
7. pg_rman restore -B $RBACKUP_PATH

everyting works fine but...
When I starts up postgresql server process.... some sort fo messages are there like:

```
cp: cannot stat `/postDATA/ARCHIVE_LOG/00000007000000000000000E': No such file or directory
```

Anyway, if everything is working well, t1, t2 tables which I created before taking full backup must be there, Am i right? If so, my scripts are bellow...

```
localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]psql -d user1db -U user1
psql (9.0.1)
Type "help" for help.

user1db=> create table t1(col1 char(1));
CREATE TABLE
user1db=> insert into t1 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t1 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t1 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t1 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t1 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t1 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t1 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t1 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t1 values('1');
INSERT 0 1

user1db=> create table t2(col1 char(1));
CREATE TABLE
user1db=> insert into t2 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t2 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t2 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t2 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t2 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t2 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t2 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t2 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> insert into t2 values('1');
INSERT 0 1
user1db=> \q

localhost.localdomain:[/home/postgres]ll
total 17592
-rwxrwxr-x 1 postgres postgres    67103 Aug 10 16:24 pg_rman-1.1.2.tar.gz
drwxrwxr-x 6 postgres postgres     4096 Aug 13 17:04 postgresql-9.0.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 postgres postgres 17898437 Aug  6 10:10 postgresql-9.0.1.tar.gz

localhost.localdomain:[/home/postgres]tar -xvzf pg_rman-1.1.2.tar.gz
pg_rman/
pg_rman/delete.c
pg_rman/pg_rman.c
pg_rman/pgut/
pg_rman/pgut/pgut.h
pg_rman/pgut/pgut-port.h
pg_rman/pgut/pgut-port.c
pg_rman/pgut/pgut.c
pg_rman/pgsql_src/
pg_rman/pgsql_src/COPYRIGHT.pgsql_src
pg_rman/pgsql_src/pg_crc.c
pg_rman/pgsql_src/pg_ctl.c
pg_rman/data/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090601/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090601/170553/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090601/170553/file_arclog.txt
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090601/170553/backup.ini
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090601/170553/srvlog/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090601/170553/arclog/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090601/170553/database/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090601/170553/database/PG_VERSION
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090601/170553/file_database.txt
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/backup/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/pg_rman.ini
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090531/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090531/170553/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090531/170553/file_arclog.txt
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090531/170553/backup.ini
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090531/170553/srvlog/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090531/170553/arclog/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090531/170553/database/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090531/170553/database/PG_VERSION
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090531/170553/file_database.txt
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/timeline_history/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090602/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090602/170553/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090602/170553/backup.ini
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090602/170553/srvlog/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090602/170553/arclog/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090602/170553/database/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090603/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090603/170553/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090603/170553/file_arclog.txt
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090603/170553/backup.ini
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090603/170553/srvlog/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090603/170553/arclog/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090603/170553/database/
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090603/170553/file_srvlog.txt
pg_rman/data/sample_backup/20090603/170553/file_database.txt
pg_rman/show.c
pg_rman/data.c
pg_rman/init.c
pg_rman/backup.c
pg_rman/dir.c
pg_rman/xlog.c
pg_rman/parray.h
pg_rman/COPYRIGHT
pg_rman/pg_rman.h
pg_rman/sql/
pg_rman/sql/option.sql
pg_rman/sql/option.sh
pg_rman/sql/backup.sql
pg_rman/sql/init.sql
pg_rman/sql/backup_restore.sh
pg_rman/sql/show_validate.sql
pg_rman/sql/backup_restore.sql
pg_rman/Makefile
pg_rman/parray.c
pg_rman/restore.c
pg_rman/catalog.c
pg_rman/util.c
pg_rman/validate.c
pg_rman/expected/
pg_rman/expected/option.out
pg_rman/expected/backup_restore.out
pg_rman/expected/show_validate.out
pg_rman/expected/init.out

localhost.localdomain:[/home/postgres]cd pg_rman

localhost.localdomain:[/home/postgres/pg_rman]make USE_PGXS=1
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o backup.o backup.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o catalog.o catalog.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o data.o data.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o delete.o delete.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o dir.o dir.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o init.o init.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o parray.o parray.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o pg_rman.o pg_rman.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o restore.o restore.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o show.o show.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o util.o util.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o validate.o validate.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o xlog.o xlog.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o pgsql_src/pg_ctl.o pgsql_src/pg_ctl.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o pgsql_src/pg_crc.o pgsql_src/pg_crc.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o pgut/pgut.o pgut/pgut.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -I. -I. -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/server -I/usr/local/pgsql/include/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o pgut/pgut-port.o pgut/pgut-port.c
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv backup.o catalog.o data.o delete.o dir.o init.o parray.o pg_rman.o restore.o show.o util.o validate.o xlog.o pgsql_src/pg_ctl.o pgsql_src/pg_crc.o pgut/pgut.o pgut/pgut-port.o -L/usr/local/pgsql/lib -lpgport -L/usr/local/pgsql/lib -lpq -L/usr/local/pgsql/lib -L/usr/lib  -Wl,-rpath,'/usr/local/pgsql/lib',--enable-new-dtags  -lpgport -lxml2 -lpam -lz -lreadline -ltermcap -lcrypt -ldl -lm  -o pg_rman

localhost.localdomain:[/home/postgres/pg_rman]make USE_PGXS=1 install
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/pgsql/bin'
/bin/sh /usr/local/pgsql/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c  pg_rman '/usr/local/pgsql/bin

localhost.localdomain:[/home/postgres/pg_rman]egrep -i "wal_level|archive_mode|archive_command" $PGDATA/postgresql.conf
wal_level = archive         # minimal, archive, or hot_standby
archive_mode = on       # allows archiving to be done
archive_command = 'cp -i %p /postDATA/ARCHIVE_LOG/%f'       # command to use to archive a logfile segment

localhost.localdomain:[/home/postgres/pg_rman]pg_rman init -B /postDATA/RBACKUP
INFO: ARCLOG_PATH is set to '/postDATA/ARCHIVE_LOG'
INFO: SRVLOG_PATH is set to '/postDATA/DATA/pg_log'

localhost.localdomain:[/home/postgres/pg_rman]cd /postDATA/RBACKUP

localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]ll
total 24
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres 4096 Aug 14 09:43 backup
-rw-rw-r-- 1 postgres postgres   73 Aug 14 09:43 pg_rman.ini
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 Aug 14 09:43 timeline_history
localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]vi pg_rman.ini
ARCLOG_PATH='/postDATA/ARCHIVE_LOG'
SRVLOG_PATH='/postDATA/DATA/pg_log'
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
~         
"pg_rman.ini" 3L, 73C
localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]pg_rman -B /postDATA/RBACKUP show
============================================================================
Start                Time   Total    Data     WAL     Log  Backup   Status  
============================================================================

localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]pg_rman backup -B /postDATA/RBACKUP -b f
INFO: database backup start
NOTICE:  pg_stop_backup complete, all required WAL segments have been archived

localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]pg_rman -B /postDATA/RBACKUP show
============================================================================
Start                Time   Total    Data     WAL     Log  Backup   Status  
============================================================================
2012-08-14 09:46:37    4m    26MB    ----   318MB    ----   344MB   DONE

localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]pg_rman -B /postDATA/RBACKUP validate
INFO: validate: 2012-08-14 09:46:37

localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]pg_rman -B /postDATA/RBACKUP show
============================================================================
Start                Time   Total    Data     WAL     Log  Backup   Status  
============================================================================
2012-08-14 09:46:37    4m    26MB    ----   318MB    ----   344MB   OK

localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]psql -d user1db -U user1
psql (9.0.1)
Type "help" for help.

user1db=> \d
       List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  | Owner 
--------+------+-------+-------
 public | t1   | table | user1
 public | t2   | table | user1
user1db=> drop table t1;
DROP TABLE
user1db=> drop table t2;
DROP TABLE
user1db=> \d
No relations found.
user1db=> \q

localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]pg_ctl stop -m fast
LOG:  received fast shutdown request
LOG:  aborting any active transactions
waiting for server to shut down....LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
LOG:  shutting down
LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]pg_rman restore -B /postDATA/RBACKUP
INFO: validate: 2012-08-14 09:46:37
INFO: restore complete. Recovery starts automatically when the PostgreSQL server is started.

localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]pg_ctl start
server starting
localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2012-08-14 09:46:57 KST
LOG:  restored log file "00000007.history" from archive
LOG:  restored log file "00000007.history" from archive
LOG:  starting archive recovery
LOG:  restored log file "00000007000000000000000C" from archive
LOG:  redo starts at 0/C000070
LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/D000000
LOG:  restored log file "00000007000000000000000D" from archive
cp: cannot stat `/postDATA/ARCHIVE_LOG/00000007000000000000000E': No such file or directory
LOG:  record with zero length at 0/E000070
LOG:  redo done at 0/E000020
LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2012-08-14 09:59:05.321848+09
cp: cannot stat `/postDATA/ARCHIVE_LOG/00000008.history': No such file or directory
LOG:  selected new timeline ID: 8
LOG:  restored log file "00000007.history" from archive
LOG:  archive recovery complete
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

localhost.localdomain:[/postDATA/RBACKUP]psql -d user1db -U user1
psql (9.0.1)
Type "help" for help.

user1db=> \d
No relations found.
```

How can I get my tables(t1, t2) back through the backup???

Comment: I faced exactly same problem. Can you please guide me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you restore the backup completely. This means that you actually restore to the point to after the tables have been dropped.

You can see that from the lines:

```
INFO: validate: 2012-08-14 09:46:37
```

and

```
LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2012-08-14 09:59:05.321848+09
```

This is probably due to the fact that you still have your archive logs left in the directory.
What you need to do is either remove everything in `/postDATA/ARCHIVE_LOG/` before doing the restore/startup of the database (here I assume that pg_rman archives all archive logs needed for the restore into the backup directory), or you need to modify the recovery.conf file and add a timestamp up to which point you want to restore (which should be a time before the drop), and add the parameter `recovery_target_time`.

pg_rman is supposed to support adding that automatically if specified, but I am not certain if that works as intended.